# Removing univariate outliers from data frame (+-3 SDs)

Tags: r, outliers

I'm so new to R that I'm having trouble finding what I need in other peoples' questions. I think my question is so easy that nobody else has bothered to ask it.

What would be the simplest code to create a new data frame which excludes data which are univariate outliers(which I'm defining as points which are 3 SDs from their condition's mean), within their condition,  on a certain variable?

I'm embarrassed to show what I've tried but here it is

```
greaterthan <- mean(dat$var2[dat$condition=="one"]) + 
               2.5*(sd(dat$var2[dat$condition=="one"]))
lessthan    <- mean(dat$var2[dat$condition=="one"]) -
               2.5*(sd(dat$var2[dat$condition=="one"]))   

withoutliersremovedone1 <-dat$var2[dat$condition=="one"] < greaterthan
```

and I'm pretty much already stuck there.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
> dat <- data.frame(
                    var1=sample(letters[1:2],10,replace=TRUE),
                    var2=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,102,3,1,2)
                   )
> dat
   var1 var2
1     b    1
2     a    2
3     a    3
4     a    1
5     b    2
6     b    3
7     a  102 #outlier
8     b    3
9     b    1
10    a    2
```

Now only return those rows which are not (`!`) greater than 2 `abs`olute `sd`'s from the `mean` of the variable in question. Obviously change 2 to however many `sd`'s you want to be the cutoff.

```
> dat[!(abs(dat$var2 - mean(dat$var2))/sd(dat$var2)) > 2,]
   var1 var2
1     b    1
2     a    2
3     a    3
4     a    1
5     b    2
6     b    3 # no outlier
8     b    3 # between here
9     b    1
10    a    2
```

Or more short-hand using the `scale` function:

```
dat[!abs(scale(dat$var2)) > 2,]

   var1 var2
1     b    1
2     a    2
3     a    3
4     a    1
5     b    2
6     b    3
8     b    3
9     b    1
10    a    2
```

**edit**

This can be extended to looking within groups using `by`

```
do.call(rbind,by(dat,dat$var1,function(x) x[!abs(scale(x$var2)) > 2,] ))
```

This assumes `dat$var1` is your variable defining the group each row belongs to.

Comment: Cheers - 1 issue with this. I want to exclude based on the mean of each group, e.g. I want to exclude cases of b which are +- 3 sds above only b's mean not the whole var 2 mean. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: And for an explanation of how that last line works: "by" splits up the data frame `dat` according to the values in `dat$var1`, each chunk gets fed to the `function(x)` defined there which returns a data frame without outliers, and then the `rbind` function is called  to merge back all the data frames from each of the `data$var1` classes as arguments - this is the magic of `do.call`.

Answer (score 4):

I use the `winsorize()` function in the [robustHD](http://cran.r-project.org/package=robustHD) package for this task.  Here is its example:

```
R> example(winsorize)

winsrzR> ## generate data
winsrzR> set.seed(1234)     # for reproducibility

winsrzR> x <- rnorm(10)     # standard normal

winsrzR> x[1] <- x[1] * 10  # introduce outlier

winsrzR> ## winsorize data
winsrzR> x
 [1] -12.070657   0.277429   1.084441  -2.345698   0.429125   0.506056  
 [7]  -0.574740  -0.546632  -0.564452  -0.890038

winsrzR> winsorize(x)
 [1] -3.250372  0.277429  1.084441 -2.345698  0.429125  0.506056 
 [7] -0.574740 -0.546632 -0.564452 -0.890038

winsrzR>
```

This defaults to median +/- 2 mad, but you can set the parameters for mean +/- 3 sd.