# How to winsorize (or remove univariate outliers) in a longitudinal dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to winsorize observations grouped by individuals in a longitudinal dataset.

I started off with this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596373/removing-univariate-outliers-from-data-frame-3-sds) about how to remove data >2 standard deviations from the mean of a variable. The author also helpfully shows how to do this within categories.

My use case is slightly different:  I have a longitudinal dataset, and I want to remove individuals who are, over time, systematically shown to be outliers.  Rather than taking out the extreme observations within subjects, I'd like to either exclude those individuals altogether (trimming the data) or replacing the bottom and top 2.5% with the cut value (winsorizing, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorising).

For example, my long-form data might look like this:

```
name time points
MJ   1    998
MJ   2    1000
MJ   3    998
MJ   4    3000
MJ   5    998
MJ   5    420
MJ   6    999
MJ   7    998
Lebron   1    9
Lebron   2    1
Lebron   3    3
Lebron   4    900
Lebron   5    4
Lebron   5    4
Lebron   6    3
Lebron   7    8
Kobe   1    2
Kobe   2    1
Kobe   3    4
Kobe   4    2
Kobe   5    1000
Kobe   5    4
Kobe   6    7
Kobe   7    9
Larry   1    2
Larry   2    1
Larry   3    4
Larry   4    2
Larry   5    800
Larry   5    4
Larry   6    7
Larry   7    9
```

If I wanted to remove the extreme observations in `points` within individuals (`name`), my code would be:

```
do.call(rbind,by(df,df$name,function(x) x[!abs(scale(x$points)) > 2,]))
```

But what I really want to do is exclude the INDIVIDUAL who is extreme (in this case, `MJ`). How would I go about doing that?

*(P.S. - insert here all of the caveats about how one should not remove outliers. This is just a robustness test!)*

Comment: Well, as a first step, you'll need to define the summary statistic based upon which you will identify somebody as an outlier. What is that statistic, and how distant from the other values should it be to be considered an outlier?

Comment: Yeah this really shouldn't be a problem at all, except we don't know what metric you would use to define that MJ is extreme.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks for pointing this out; I will add a clarification to my question. The initial goal was to conduct a 95% Winsorization, in which the observations for the bottom 2.5% of individuals and top 2.5% of individuals would be replaced with the cut value. (See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorising).  However, an answer that just "trimmed" those observations would be equally useful, as the problem is in identification not removal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use dplyr:

```
test <- read.csv("test.csv", header=TRUE)
library(dplyr)

test <- test %.% 
  group_by(name) %.% 
  mutate(mean_points=mean(points))

cut_point_top <- quantile(test$mean_points, 0.95)
cut_point_bottom <- quantile(test$mean_points, 0.05)

test <- test %.% 
  group_by(name) %.% 
  mutate(outlier_top = (mean_points >= cut_point_top), 
         outlier_bottom = mean_points <= cut_point_bottom) %.%
  filter(!outlier_top & ! outlier_bottom)
```

This filters out MJ as having a mean score in the top 2.5% and Larry as being in the bottom 2.5%.

If you want to replace the points variable with the cut points for the 2.5 percentiles, just drop the last filter statement like so:

```
test <- test %.% 
  group_by(name) %.% 
  mutate(outlier_top = (mean_points >= cut_point_top), 
         outlier_bottom = mean_points <= cut_point_bottom) 

test$points <- ifelse(test$outlier_top, cut_point_top, 
                      ifelse(test$outlier_bottom, cut_point_bottom, test$points))
```

Comment: I like your answer, but how would you go about replacing the top and bottom 2.5% with the cut points?

Comment: Thanks. I've amended my answer to deal with this situation.

Comment: Second solution would be easier by using `pmin` and `pmax`

Comment: Any thoughts on how to use pmin or pmax for winsorizing? I was thinking of pmax(pmin(points, quantile(points, .95)), quantile(points, .05)). But then the trick is to insert this in the data frame as a new column. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might go about it:

```
means <- ddply(df, .(name), summarize, mean=mean(points))$mean
means <- mean(means)

upperBound <- 2

outlierTest <- ddply(df, .(name), summarize, outlier=ifelse(sum(points) / means > upperBound, 
TRUE, FALSE))

keep <- outlierTest$name[!outlierTest$outlier]

df <- df[df$name %in% keep, ]
```

where df is your data.frame.  You can choose whatever `upperBound` you want.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be appropriate for your data, but I'm going to attempt a general solution to get you started thinking. I suggest using robust statistics such as median and median absolute devation (MAD) to define your outliers. You can start by taking a look at the proportion of points that are outliers (compared to all points) for each individual:

Let `df` be your data frame

```
library(plyr)

med <- median(df$points)
md <- mad(df$points)
outlier.factor <- 2
daply(df, .(name), function(x) {sum(abs(x$points - m) > md * outlier.factor) / nrow(x)})
```

The last line outputs the following (for your example data):

```
 Kobe  Larry Lebron     MJ
0.125  0.125  0.125  1.000
```

So all the points for `MJ` are outliers, while 12.5% are outliers for all other individuals.

You can now use a threshold to choose which individuals to remove. For example, for normally distributed data, you would expect about 4.55% to fall outside the range median ± 2 x MAD.