# removing outliers from data frame (+-2 SDs)

Tags: r, outliers

I have a data.frame that has all my subjects (20 in total) and their reaction times per condition (3 in total). See below for example.

I would like to remove outliers from the mean of each condition for each subject

I used this code:

```
dat<- do.call(rbind,by(dat,dat$condition,function(x) x[!abs(scale(x$rt_raw)) > 2,] ))
```

but it seems to group each row by condition, not by condition and subject.
Is there another way of doing it? Or am I wrong?

```
rt_raw       subject    condition 

 0.9193426       1      L        
 0.7985855       1      C         
 0.7000456       1      S        
 0.8501735       2      C        
 0.715198        2      S         
 0.7865169       2      L
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does look your expected output? I tried it with the `iris` dataset and your code seems to work fine.

Comment: I am just not sure if the code takes into account the mean of each subject per condition to remove trials that are 2.0 SD above the mean or if it looks at the mean of all subjects per condition and removes the trials that are above.

Comment: Thanks Ang. I thought so. Do you know of a way in which we can look at the mean of each subject per condition and remove trials that way?

Comment: Here it is assumed that each row (not each subject) belongs to one group and the code looks at the mean within groups. So it considers the mean of all subjects per condition, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596373/removing-univariate-outliers-from-data-frame-3-sds)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rough solution. The idea here is to create two variables for mean and standard deviation of condition to consider this "mean of each subject per condition" case. 
Then trials are removed based on the mean of each subject per condition.

```
dat <- data.frame(rt_raw = runif(12, 1, 10),
                  subject = sort(rep(1:3, 4)),
                  condition = rep(c("L", "C", "S"), 4))

# mean and sd per condition, for each subject (each row)
dat$mean.condition <- by(dat$rt_raw, dat$condition, mean)
dat$sd.condition <- by(dat$rt_raw, dat$condition, sd)
# remove outliers 
dat2 <- dat[!(abs(dat$rt_raw - dat$mean.condition)/dat$sd.condition) > 1, ]
dat3 <- dat[!(abs(dat$rt_raw - dat$mean.condition)/dat$sd.condition) > 1.5, ]
dat4 <- dat[!(abs(dat$rt_raw - dat$mean.condition)/dat$sd.condition) > 2, ]
```